# How do I access data from a Heroku application through the Workbench?

Tags: mysql, heroku, mysql-workbench

have a question about Heroku, when accessing the database by the Workbench does not appear the tables, even after accessing the address of my web application:

http://cliente-mws-usp-app51.herokuapp.com/universidade/listarUniversidades.jsp

The data appears on the List Universities page, but the MySQL Workbench is not displaying the tables even after giving a Refresh All.

I already delete the server and client application and created a new application as follows:

**Copy Application Creation Commands**

```
$> sudo heroku fork -a mws-usp mws-usp-app51
$> sudo heroku fork -a cliente-mws-usp cliente-mws-usp-app51
$> sudo heroku config:set MWS_USP_URL=https://mws-usp-app51.herokuapp.com/rest/ -a cliente-mws-usp-app51
```

**Copy Application Settings Commands**

```
$> sudo heroku config --app mws-usp-app51
=== mws-usp-app51 Config Vars
CLEARDB_DATABASE_URL:         mysql://<user>:<password>@us-cdbr-iron-east-04.cleardb.net/heroku_bcb53a522cec107?reconnect=true
DATABASE_URL:                 postgres://...:...@ec2-23-21-73-32.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dalmmfh5cs6nqa
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_PURPLE_URL: postgres://...:...@ec2-54-235-240-76.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dbrdf0bgaj05i4
JAVA_OPTS:                    -XX:+UseCompressedOops

$> sudo heroku config --app cliente-mws-usp-app51
=== cliente-mws-usp-app51 Config Vars
BUILDPACK_URL:               https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-java.git
DATABASE_URL:                postgres://...:...@ec2-54-163-239-102.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dcfjmp9me0f8eg
HEROKU_APP_ID:               bf4dace5-8f8f-43e5-a4a4-98a6f1be98d5
HEROKU_APP_NAME:             cliente-mws-usp
HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_AMBER_URL: postgres://...:....@ec2-54-243-204-195.compute-1.amazonaws.com:5432/dv4susdttc84s
HEROKU_RELEASE_VERSION:      v246
HEROKU_SLUG_COMMIT:          773238be7a854ff75cd09c186d73d3bd7121645e
HEROKU_SLUG_DESCRIPTION:     Deploy 773238b
JAVA_OPTS:                   -XX:+UseCompressedOops
MWS_USP_URL:                 https://mws-usp-app51.herokuapp.com/rest/
```

​I do not know why the data is still there, even after I delete the application and create a new one, I no longer know what to do and the worst of it is that I do not know what I did wrong. What should I do in this case?

[image]
[image]